# Finite difference scheme for solving nonlinear least-squares problem

Tags: finite-difference, nonlinear-equations, discretization, nonconvex

I am dealing with following problem:

$$
\min_{u,\gamma}\Bigg\{ \frac{1}{1000}  \iint_{S_2} {\gamma (x,y)^2 dxdy} + \iint_{S_2} {[u(x,y)  - u_0 (x,y)]^2 dxdy} + \iint_{S_2} {[\Delta u(x,y) - \gamma (x,y) u(x,y)]^2 dxdy}\Bigg\}
$$

where the unknown functions $u(x, y)$ and $\gamma(x, y)$ are defined on the unit square $S_2$ and the function $u_0(x, y)$ is defined on $S_2$ by $u_0(x, y) = \sin(6\pi x) \sin(2\pi y)$.

This problem should be discretized using 5-point finite differences.

I have no experience discretizing such problems. Could somebody help me out, or point me to right literature to look for some examples?

Note: this problem comes from the paper [Recursive trust-region methods for multiscale nonlinear optimization](http://www.cerfacs.fr/algor/reports/2006/TR_PA_06_32.pdf) (page 10)

Comment: Could you try to make the equation easier to read using [LaTeX](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-i-format-mathematical-expressions-using-mathjax/328#328)?

Comment: I think there might be a bug in the middle term. As written, that's identically zero. Presumably one of those $u$ terms must be a $u_0$, but I'll let you fix it.

Comment: you are right, I was missing subscript in one term

Comment: What kind of operation does $\Delta$ perform on $u(x,y)$?

Comment: @fibonatic do u have any suggestion? I am mostly curious how to deal with last term

Comment: @AK135 I assume that $\Delta$ is the [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del#Laplacian), which can also be written as $\nabla^2$, in which case I would think that [this link](http://www.physics.arizona.edu/~restrepo/475B/Notes/sourcehtml/node51.html) might the useful.

Comment: @fibonatic Yes $\Delta$ is Laplace operator, which is clear how to obtain, but I do not know, how to combine it with integral, any hints?

Comment: @AK135 I have very little experience with this, but this looks like an optimal control problem.The 5-point finite differences tells you how to find $\Delta u(x,y)$ when you discretize $x$ and $y$. The integrals can be found by using finite element method (not sure if you have to use linear elements, or if quadratic elements would also be a possibility).

Comment: @fibonatic I am not sure if there is a need for combinations of FEM and finite differences ... at least what I am hoping for...

Comment: @AK135 I would think that you do have to assume some interpolated function in order to be able to evaluate the integrals. In this case I think you should be able to evaluate the integral analytically, since there are mainly quadratic terms. In order to find the minimum you can either take the partial derivative of the value of each discrete point and solve for them such that they are all zero, or do this numerically by iteratively evaluating each point with something like the golden search algorithm.

Comment: @AK135 - another way of avoiding evaluating the integral could be to analytically minimize the integral using the calculus of variations - essentially taking the functional derivative with respect to $u(x,y)$ and $\gamma(x,y)$ and setting them equal to zero.  This would then give you some fourth order PDEs, which you could solve with finite differences.  (This is similar to fibonatic's suggestion, but might be easier.)  Of course, as always, you need to make sure you're in a local minimum, not a local maximum...

Comment: @AJK I just want to add remark, because this $\min_{\gamma, u}$  might be misleading here. I am trying to get objective function out of the problem, which I can then run through solver in order to minimize. If this is a case, is it ok to apply your approaches?

Comment: @AK135 - If that is what you want to do, my suggestion would not give you the objective function, but it would provide a route to determine $\gamma$ and $u$.

Comment: @AK135 - Could you provide a bit more information on this problem?  Are you trying to find a local minimum or a global minimum?  Are there boundary conditions on $u$ and $\gamma$? Why do you need to use a 5 point finite difference - is this a homework problem?

Comment: @AJK  I am implementing a Trust region non-linear solver - which aims to global convergence and I would like to compare my solution to the one obtained in following paper (where author uses different strategy ) : http://www.cerfacs.fr/algor/reports/2006/TR_PA_06_32.pdf on page 10. That's where problem comes from.

Comment: @AK135, ok will think about this.  I also added this link to the question, which I think will help clarify the context a bit.

Comment: @AJK thanks, any suggestions are welcomed, I am being stucked with this problem for long time already ...